# Как получить в результате поиска определённый набор полей?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/3click/text/_search" -d'
{
   "query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "content" : "в лесу родилась ёлочка"
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "content": { }
    }
}
}'
```

Делаю такой запрос.
Мне возвращается всё правильно, но эластик возвращает значение полей `content` для найденных записей полностью. А там сотни кб текста. Мне же нужно, чтобы поиск шёл по полю `content`, но получать я хочу `_id` и фрагменты `highlight`, а `content` нам не нужен. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "_source": ["account_number", "balance"]
}'
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/_executing_searches.html
Нашёл. Чтение инструкций облегчает совесть. Можно закрывать.